# In R, how can I get a combination of every element in a list and then concatenate them?

Tags: r

I have a list, and I am trying to choose a specific number from it. For example:

```
x <- list()
x[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
x[[2]] <- c(4,5,6)
x[[3]] <- c(7,8,9)
```

Now I do this:

> y <- combn(x,2)

y looks like this:

```
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     

[1,] Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3

[2,] Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
```

A matrix is returned with columns representing each set. However, I want to concatenate them column-wise, but I cannot do so.

> cbind(y)

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     

[1,] Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3

[2,] Numeric,3 Numeric,3 Numeric,3
```

There should be only one row, but there are two! In addition, when I concatenate specific elements, this happens:

> c(y[1,1],y[2,1])

```
[[1]]

[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]

[1] 4 5 6
```

This is just an example. The actual list is much larger. How can I accomplish this? Basically, I'm trying to do k-fold cross validation but each subset of the data is in a list.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: "k fold cross validation"... Have you looked into `library(caret)`?

Comment: I want a list that contains every single combination of 2 out of 3 of the elements in the original list.

Comment: I haven't looked into caret, but I've already partitioned it, so I don't think I really need that library. A combination of a list and then concatenating the elements should be pretty simple.

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking at caret to handle the cross-validation for you. It will significantly reduce your codes complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example, since your list is not of equal length, you can try this:

```
for(counter in i : ncol(y)){
    newList[[counter]] <- do.call(c, y[1 : 2, counter]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can take combinations of the list indexes, and for each combination combine the two corresponding list components into a vector.

To preserve the list structure we must pass `simplify=F` to [`combn()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html):

```
combn(seq_along(x),2L,function(i) c(x[[i[1L]]],x[[i[2L]]]),simplify=F);
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3 7 8 9
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
##
```

---

Actually there's an even easier way to do it:

```
combn(x,2L,unlist,simplify=F);
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3 7 8 9
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
##
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question I think what you want is to make each list a column in a matrix. Please correct your question if this is not the case.

What you want to use is do.call(). I recommend looking at the documentation for this function (`?do.call`) - but briefly it executes a function on a list.

```
x <- list()
x[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
x[[2]] <- c(4,5,6)
x[[3]] <- c(7,8,9)

do.call(cbind, x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: It works, but the length of the elements in my real list are not the same? What do I do?

Comment: In this case - you probably don't want to be storing things in a matrix. What is your end goal?

Comment: My end goal is to do k-fold cross validation. I want to take every single combination of a subset of my data (but the subsets are not all the same length). It is the combn function that returns the matrix. How can I stop this?

Comment: Assuming that your lists contain the indices of your data for each fold. I would keep the elements in list form and iterate through the list to subset your main dataset. I don't think you need them in a matrix - which is what your question is asking.

Comment: Assuming you are not using the inbuilt functions in R for K-fold cross validation for some reason (see caret package)

Comment: Yes, but I still need to choose 2 of the three elements in the list and then combine them to be my training dataset. Then the left over set will be my validation set. My question is how can I do so?

Comment: I figured that I could call the combn function on it then concatenate

Comment: So you always need to choose the first 2? But there is not always 3 items right? Because you previously said there was not always the same number of items

Comment: No, I need to choose an arbitrary number. I've just been using 2 as the example case

Answer (score 1):

We can use this within `combn` itself as it has the `FUN` argument.

```
combn(1:3, 2, FUN = function(i) list(do.call(cbind, x[i])))
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    7
#[2,]    2    8
#[3,]    3    9

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    7
#[2,]    5    8
#[3,]    6    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a matrix of indices with `combn` and `apply` across it, `do.call(cbind, ...)`ing each pair. You'll need an extra `list()` call so `apply` doesn't simplify everything into one matrix:

```
apply(combn(1:3, 2), 2, function(i){list(do.call(cbind, x[i]))})
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2    5
## [3,]    3    6
## 
## 
## [[2]]
## [[2]][[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    7
## [2,]    2    8
## [3,]    3    9
## 
## 
## [[3]]
## [[3]][[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    7
## [2,]    5    8
## [3,]    6    9
```

The elements are annoyingly nested, but a `purrr::flatten()` call neatens the structure easily enough.